# Data structuring from Dataframes to firestore

Tags: angular, python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am working on calculating correlation matrix, and analyzing data. So my outputs can have different formats as show in the figure below.

I want to store these data in Firestore but I found myself struggling when I try to **get** the data from firebase using angular as it has different structure. 
[image: image1]

I was thinking about defining a function or a class to have a common strucutre for all data and push them to firebase.

I managed to push python ouput to firestore, but in different structure as shown in the following image.
[image: image2]